# Control orientation when using view flipper

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, viewflipper

I have three layouts with viewflipper.  I want one layout to be able to change orientation but the other two to stay in portrait mode.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your layouts as type linear layout so you can use the `android:orientation` feature for the layout. So you can do `android:orientation="horizontal/vertical"`, `android:orientation="horizontal"`, and `android:orientation="vertical"` for your different layouts.

Comment: What about relative layout?  Does android:orientation in xml force it to stay in the stated orientation?

Comment: No, relative layout does not have this feature. Though, you could create a linear layout that contains the relative layout which contains all the views. This way nothing is changed with the views and you can still change the orientation of the layout.

Comment: Just thought the same thing!  Thanks